# getting a NSDate from NSCalendar and NSDateComponents

Tags: timezone, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

My code is like below

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.year = [aDay.year intValue];   // 2012
components.month = [aDay.month intValue]; // 2
components.day = [aDay.day intValue];  // 1
components.hour = components.minute = components.second = 0;
NSDate *now = [self.calender dateFromComponents:components];
```

and about self.calendar, I tried both the 2 methods:

```
self.calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
self.calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

but after this, when I print the date "now", it is always this:

```
(gdb) po now
2012-01-31 16:00:00 +0000
```

The date "now" is supposed to be 2012-02-01 00:00:00

Apparently there is 8 hours difference, and I'm now in China so I am in a +0800 timezone I guess?

How could I fix this problem? Do I have to deal with the timeZone?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't you try setting the timezone to one of your liking:

```
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"];
[calendar setTimeZone:zone];
```

You can see a list of the known time zones with:

```
NSArray *timezones = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
NSLog(@"%@", timezones);
```

Comment: Thanks! So the problems is still about time zone? Is there any method to directly get the user's current time zone? just like [NSCalendar currentCalendar]?

Comment: I've check the default timeZone, it's is default Asia/Hebin, so... what can I do.?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out.

What it displays is correct since the NSDate conserves the absolute time, so the time zone is always +0000,

and it is better to keep it this way since I need compare: method in NSDate,etc

the only difference is when you are going to translate the absolute date to local date readable string for users, just take care of it.